# Can someone help me with Pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

The variable X starts with the value 0.
    The variable Y starts with the value 5.
    Add 1 to X.
    Add 1 to Y.
    Add X and Y, and store the result in Y.
    Display the value in Y on the screen.

Output #1:

Pseudocode #1:

The logic of the question makes sense, but I do not even know where to start. Can someone explain and/or help me?

Comment: Start with the first step (a variable named X). Set it's value to 0. Continue from there, one step at a time.

Comment: Sounds like homework, in which case you should ask for an example so you give the expected format.... I put mine below. Pseudocode is a loose term and means different things to different people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
X = 0;
Y = 5;
X = X + 1;
Y = Y + 1;
Y = X + Y;
display(Y);
```

I'll leave the maths to you...